# Is it possible to assign a time limit on sklearn RandomizedSearchCV?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I am trying to tune some parameters using sklearn package and RandomizedSearchCV (I might use GridSearchCV as well) function. The problem I encounter is that for some classification algorithm and parameters, stuck at some point and does not finish overnight. I want to give assign some time limit, like 30 min for each run. If training does not finish in 30 min, just kill the process and run the next one.